# Sequential Directory Names Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, sequential

Im trying to generate directories that are numbered 1 to however many. because in python you have to convert an integer to string, which changes it to lexicographical, how do I still keep the order of the directories?

I want the directories when generated to look like this

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4
dir5
dir6
...
```

Instead I get the output of

```
dir0
dir1
dir10
dir11
dir12
dir13
dir14
...
dir19
dir2
dir20
dir21
dir22
dir23
...
```

my code

```
totaldir = 20
while (x < totaldir):
    x += 1
    print ("start!!!")
    makestr = str("dir%s" % x)
    makedir = os.makedirs(makestr, mode=0o755, exist_ok=True)
    print (makedir)
    print ("ended!!!")
```

Comment: Why does it matter which order you make the directories in? You can make them sort the same numerically and lexicographically by padding with zeroes, e.g. `"dir%02d" % x`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks! it works for the most part haha. I tried creating 1000 directories and the order is screwed up when I look with the terminal, but when I look with the file explorer, its properly ordered.

Comment: If you're making thousands, you will need `"dir%04d" % s` to have enough digits to sort correctly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks! I apologize but is there a way to not have a set 0's in place so it sorts correctly? Is it possible to set 0's and have them sort correctly?

Comment: If whatever you're using sorts lexicographically, then no.

Answer (score 2):

By output you mean you are seeing them that way in the directory from a File viewer software ( explorer in windows ).

That is because the fileviewer / explorer has been configured ( by default ) to display the contents in alphabetically sorted manner. By alphabetically sorted manner `10` comes **before** `2`, hence the order of `dir0` then `dir1` then `dir10` .

If you want them to be displayed the way you expect, follow @jonrsharpe's suggestion of 0 padding the file number, so that they remain alphabetically in the same order as their numerical order.

Comment: Most modern file explorers do sort post-fixed numbers separately, makes me wonder what OP is using.

Comment: I was using terminal with 'ls -la' and sometimes the order was off, but when viewing with a file explorer, its ordered. And Im also using meth.

Comment: @catalyst Wait, what?

Comment: Im on mac. I viewed the directory of which I created the sequential directories with Terminal, which ordered the directories oddly was in a fashion of 0, 1, 10, 11, 12, ..., 2, 20, 21, 22... So on.